# How to use mapState in js files?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want to access my states from a `.js` file using `mapState` in Vue.js.

I've tried

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

const foo = {
  ...mapState(['axios']),
};

foo.axios.get('...');
```

but it doesn't work. The error is

```
TypeError: foo.axios.get is not a function
```

What should I do to achieve that?

I have searched for other questions, but they access from `store.state. ...` instead of using `mapState` which I want.

Comment: `mapState` creates functions. Have you tried `foo.axios().get('...')`?

Comment: @skirtle Doesn't work, `TypeError: this.$store is undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure using `mapState` is a good idea as it's very much intended to be used as a way to create computed properties on a component.

However, it can be made to work like this:

```js
const foo = {
  $store: store,
  ...mapState(['axios'])
};

foo.axios().get('...');
```

You can see the implementation of `mapState` here:

https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/helpers.js#L7

Note that it relies on `this.$store` to get a reference to the store. On a component this will be injected automatically but for your object it needs adding manually.

The other thing to note is that I'm having to invoke `axios()` as a method. Computed properties on components are defined as functions but accessed as properties but that magic trick is performed internally by Vue. On a normal JavaScript object like this there is no such magic so we just have to call the function as a function. Other benefits of computed properties, such as the caching, will also be lost.

Comment: Wow! Nice answer!